# How to set AppBarButton text with String resource using XAML

Tags: windows, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Is there a way to set a string resource as the text for an AppBarButton rather than having to do it programmatically? The method used below doesn't work for some reason.

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <Button 
                    Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" 
                    Name="BackButton" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                    Click="Back_Click"/>
            </CommandBar.Content>

            <AppBarButton Name="HelloWorld" x:Uid="HelloWorld">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE110;"/>
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar>
        <Frame Name="MyFrame"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: It works, maybe you can paste more code.

Comment: Hello, if you want to localize, you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/app-resources/localize-strings-ui-manifest) to set up. If there are some problems, maybe you can provide a minimum runable demo so that we can analyze your problem.

Comment: @Vincent added full page code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code didn't work, maybe related to the `Resources.resw` file.
Fisrt as Richard Zhang - MSFT said, you need to create a `Strings` folder, and create the corresponding localize folder.
[image]

In `Resources.resw`, new a key/value called `HelloWorld.Label`, set value to `Hello World!`

[image]

Be attention, we are setting the `AppBarButton`'s `Label`. If you set the key to "HelloWorld", then nothing happens.
[image]

Comment: What about using `HelloWorld.Label` for a `TextView`?

Comment: Use `TextBox.Text` instead, cause you are setting `TextBox`'s `Text` property.

Comment: I'm using the same name though. i.e. "Hello World!". VS won't let me use `HelloWorld.Text` when `HelloWorld.Label` is already there.